# Regex and repetitive replacment

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Consider following code:

```
 echo preg_replace('#(\w) (\w) (\w)#','{\1}<\2>{\3}',$string);
```

If `$string= 'a b c';` it will yield `{a}<b>{c}`. How modify it that `$string='a b b b c'` return :`{a}<b><b><b><b>{c}`

What about this: `a a a  b b b c c c`

It's just an example. Please answer in general.

Comment: What should be output for string `a a a b b b c c c` ?

Comment: @anubhava ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`{a}{a}{a}<b><b><b>{c}{c}{c}` or ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`{a}{a}{a}<b><b><b>(c)(c)(c)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$new=preg_replace(array('#(\w) (.*) (\w)#','#(.*?) #'),array('{\1}<\2>{\3}','\1><'),$string);
```

for example if your string is `'a b b b c'` at first preg_replace with first pattern `#(\w) (.*) (\w)#` and first replacement `'{\1}<\2>{\3}'` process the string that result is  `{a}<b b b>{c}` next preg_replace with second pattern `'#(.*?) #'` and second replacement `'\1><'` process  `{a}<b b b>{c}` in this process replace space with `><` now the $new result is `{a}<b><b><b>{c}`.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer a little?

Comment: @PHPst see the answer. i try to explain it with example i hope help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that should work for you

```
$str='a a a b b b c c c';
$regex = array('/\b(a)\b\s*/', '/\b(b)\b\s*/', '/\b(c)\b\s*/');
$repl = array('{\1}', '<\1>', '{\1}');

$nstr = preg_replace($regex, $repl, $str);
echo "$nstr\n";
// OUTPUT: {a}{a}{a}<b><b><b>{c}{c}{c}
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/gxa3pg